# Checking programmatically when creating an instance from machine image will become possible

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-compute-api

My framework uses Python API for GCE to create instances on the fly as needed. All the instances are based on single machine image. There is a limit on the rate of the instance-creation operation. However, I noticed that sometimes GCE allows the creation of several instances in a row without much delay. Hence, I do not want to fix the delay between instance creations in my code.

For now, I use exponentially increasing delays between attempts at instance creation. Although I could not find anything related in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/), I decided to try asking: is there a way to use the API to find out directly when the next instance creation will be allowed?

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if your question included a minimal repro of your code, it's scope (what rate of instance creation are you attempting?) and details of the error that you're receiving.

Although not surprising (!), I was unaware that there is a rate limit on instance creation ([`instances.insert`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/insert)).

The Compute Engine [API rate limits](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api-rate-limits) does not appear (!?) to include `instances.insert`.

If you're hitting a rate limit you can:

1. Use Cloud Monitoring (libraries) to [monitor API usage](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/monitoring#using). For a non-programmatic (!) check, [API dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/compute.googleapis.com/quotas) is easier.
2. It's good practice to include a feedback mechanism in your code. For example, if you encounter service-side errors (5XX), you should backoff retries.
3. You can request more [Compute Engine](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?service=compute.googleapis.com) quota using Cloud console.

It's possible that you're encountering service capacity limits (I've seen these recently in us-east1). There is insufficient capacity to fulfill your requests in the region|zone. In this case, the only alternative is to look in other regions|zones for capacity.

Comment: It is certainly a rate limit, as my code always succeeds in creating another instance after waiting for a few minutes. I am working on a framework for scientific experimentation, so it's for other people's use. Hence, asking for more quota is not a suitable solution.